# Prevent multiple login from a user in the same session

Tags: session, wicket

How to prevent multiple login from a user in the same session in Wicket?

Comment: Could you explain your use case please? This is quite ambiguous as it is stated now.

Comment: if i login with a user, and after that i login again with the same user, i want to invalidate the other session so that to not have 2 session opened for the same user

Answer (score 0):

you can create a table in your database to hold  the ids of logged in users.
when a user logs in check if his id is in said table
otherwise insert his id into that table.
you also need to remove the user's id from the table once user logs out

Answer (score 0):

you can integrate spring security with wicket. Spring security handles it automatically.